# How do I use a global variable in Jinja2 using namespace class?

Tags: python, html, flask, namespaces, jinja2

So, I have been trying to create a global variable in Jinja2 template that will be available across all the loops and blocks. I am trying to use the namespace class of Jinja2 . However, I run into the following problem.

HTML -

```
{% set ns = namespace(items=0) %}
{% for line in range(3) %}
    {% set ns.items = ns.items + line %}
{% endfor %}

{{ ns.items }}
```

Python -

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def index():
    return render_template('index_test.html')
```

Error-

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of statement block', got '.'

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1997, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
raise value
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
raise value
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\flask_login\utils.py", line 261, in decorated_view
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Boudhayan Dev\Desktop\Segregator\app\routes.py", line 19, in index
return render_template('index_test.html')
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 133, in render_template
return _render(ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 869, in get_or_select_template
return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 830, in get_template
return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 804, in _load_template
template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\jinja2\loaders.py", line 125, in load
code = environment.compile(source, name, filename)
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 591, in compile
self.handle_exception(exc_info, source_hint=source_hint)
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\jinja2\_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "C:\Users\Boudhayan Dev\Desktop\Segregator\app\templates\index_test.html", line 3, in template
{% set ns.items = ns.items + line %}
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 497, in _parse
return Parser(self, source, name, encode_filename(filename)).parse()
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 896, in parse
result = nodes.Template(self.subparse(), lineno=1)
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 878, in subparse
rv = self.parse_statement()
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 130, in parse_statement
return getattr(self, 'parse_' + self.stream.current.value)()
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 198, in parse_for
body = self.parse_statements(('name:endfor', 'name:else'))
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 165, in parse_statements
result = self.subparse(end_tokens)
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 878, in subparse
rv = self.parse_statement()
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 130, in parse_statement
return getattr(self, 'parse_' + self.stream.current.value)()
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 184, in parse_set
drop_needle=True)
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 164, in parse_statements
self.stream.expect('block_end')
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\jinja2\lexer.py", line 386, in expect
self.name, self.filename)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of statement block', got '.'
```

The above code is as per the Jinja2 documentation but in spite of that it results into error.Please help me find the solution.

Comment: What version of Jinja2 do you have installed?

Comment: jinja2.__version__= 2.9.6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The namespaces feature was introduced in Jinja2 version 2.10, see the [*Assignments* section](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#assignments):

> New in version 2.10: Added support for namespace objects

Your error indicates your version is older; with 2.10 the code works without change:

```
>>> import jinja2
>>> jinja2.__version__
'2.10'
>>> from jinja2 import Template
>>> template = Template('''\
... {% set ns = namespace(items=0) %}
... {% for line in range(3) %}
...     {% set ns.items = ns.items + line %}
... {% endfor %}
...
... {{ ns.items }}
... ''')
>>> template.render().strip()
'\n\n    \n\n    \n\n    \n\n\n3'
```

Make sure you upgrade to 2.10; this is the newest version at this time, released Nov 8, 2017.